# Material UI textfield error not working properly in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using a functional component and Material UI. I have created a form with 2 textfields. I want to enable the error prop only when a particular condition is fulfilled. And the conditions are checked only when the submit button is clicked. Somehow it checks only few of the conditions. I am confused why this is happening.

**Code:**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import image from '../images/app_icon_without_bg.png'

import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button/index'
import MuiThemeProvider from '@material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider'
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar'
import {amber} from '@material-ui/core/colors'
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import {styled} from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import {Redirect} from "react-router-dom"

const MyCard = styled(Card)({

    borderRadius: 20,
    // boxShadow:'0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
    background: '#f3f3f3',
    boxShadow: '6px 6px 10px 0px rgba(112,112,112,0.16), -6px -6px 10px 0px #FFFFFF',
    padding: '50px 10px',
})


const MyAvatar = styled(Avatar)({
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #008080 30%, #20B2AA 90%)',
    border: 0,
    color: 'white',
    height: 90,
    width: 90,
    margin: "auto",

})

const MyButton = styled(Button)({
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #008080 30%, #20B2AA 90%)',
    border: 0,
    color: 'white',
    width: 100,
    justifyContent: "center",
    textDecoration: "none",
    boxShadow: '0px 8px 10px -5px rgba(124,133,133,1)'
    // margin:"auto"
})


// const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
//     root: {
//         display: 'flex',
//         '& > *': {
//             margin: theme.spacing(1),
//         },
//     },
//
//
//     amber: {
//         backgroundColor: amber[500],
//         width: theme.spacing(7),
//         height: theme.spacing(7),
//
//     },
//
//     button_color:{
//         backgroundColor: amber[500],
//
//     }
//
//
// }))


function Login() {
    // const classes = useStyles()


    //USE EFFECT
    useEffect(() => {
        }, []
    )

    //SETTING THE STATES
    // const [username,setUserName]=useState('')
    // const [password,setPassword]=useState('')
    // const [errorMessage,setErrorMessage]=useState('')

    const [form, setForm] = useState({
        username: '',
        password: '',
        errorUser: false,
        errorPassword: false,
        helperTextUserName: '',
        helperTextPassword: '',


    })


    const changeHandler = (event) => {
        setForm({
            ...form,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })
    }


    //POSTING USERNAME AND PASSWORD TO DB
    function handleClick() {

        const userObject = {
            userName: form.username,
            password: form.password
        }

        let username = form.username
        let password = form.password
        let letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/
        let err = ''


        if (username !== '' && !username.match(letters)) {
            // err = <p>Please enter your username.</p>
            setForm({
                helperTextUserName: 'Please use alphanumerics.',
                errorUser: true
            })
        }
        if (username === '') {
            // err = <p>Please enter your username.</p>
            setForm({
                helperTextUserName: 'Please enter your username.',
                errorUser: true
            })

        } else if (password === '') {
            // err = <p>Please enter your password.</p>
            setForm({
                helperTextPassword: 'Please enter your password.',
                errorPassword: true
            })


        } else if (username === '' && password === '') {
            // err = <p>Please fill the fields to proceed.</p>
            setForm({
                helperTextUserName: 'Please fill the fields.',
                errorUser: true,
                errorPassword: true
            })

        } else {
            axios.post(`/api/login`, userObject)
                .then(window.location = "/home")
                .catch(err => console.error(err))

        }

    }


    return (

        <div className='login'>
            <MyCard className='card'>

                <div>

                    <img src={image} width="90" height="100px"/>
                    <p className={'card-heading-main'}>COMPLAINT MANAGEMENT SYSTEM</p>

                    <form>
                        <TextField
                            error={form.errorUser}
                            helperText={form.helperTextUserName}
                            autoFocus
                            id="outlined-basic"
                            variant="outlined"
                            type="username"
                            label="Username"
                            name={'username'}
                            className={'login-input'}
                            placeholder="john123"
                            onChange={changeHandler}
                        />
                        <br/>
                        <br/>

                        <TextField
                            error={form.errorPassword}
                            helperText={form.helperTextPassword}
                            id="outlined-basic"
                            variant="outlined"
                            label="Password"
                            name={'password'}
                            className={'login-input'}
                            type="password"
                            onChange={changeHandler}
                        />

                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <MyButton onClick={handleClick}>Submit</MyButton>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </MyCard>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Comment: This question was edited into an answer with no question, which we don't do here. I have rolled it back to the original question state, so that the answer below makes sense. You are welcome to write a self-answer with the changes you made to the question's code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent default submit button behavior, and you forgot to merge in previous state, which caused incorrect data to be placed in the state.  (`username` or `password` == `undefined` will pass all your checks)

```js
//POSTING USERNAME AND PASSWORD TO DB
function handleClick(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const userObject = {
        userName: form.username,
        password: form.password
    }

    let username = form.username
    let password = form.password
    let letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/
    let err = ''

    if (username !== '' && !username.match(letters)) {
        // err = <p>Please enter your username.</p>
        setForm({
          ...form,
            helperTextUserName: 'Please use alphanumerics.',
            errorUser: true
        })
    }
    if (username === '') {
        // err = <p>Please enter your username.</p>
        setForm({
          ...form,
            helperTextUserName: 'Please enter your username.',
            errorUser: true
        })

    } else if (password === '') {
        // err = <p>Please enter your password.</p>
        setForm({
          ...form,
            helperTextPassword: 'Please enter your password.',
            errorPassword: true
        })


    } else if (username === '' && password === '') {
        // err = <p>Please fill the fields to proceed.</p>
        setForm({
          ...form,
            helperTextUserName: 'Please fill the fields.',
            errorUser: true,
            errorPassword: true
        })

    } else {
        axios.post(`/api/login`, userObject)
            .then(window.location = "/home")
            .catch(err => console.error(err))

    }

}
```